# removing a transition strip between linoleum and hardwood

Tags: floor, hardwood, transition

I am going to tile an entrance way that is currently linoleum.  The transition strip between the linoleum and a hardwood floor is glued down, it appears that it may be construction adhesive, very strong.  How can I remove this strip without damaging the hardwood floor?

Comment: Of what material is the "transition strip"? Metal?  If so, some adhesives can be softened using a heat gun so it can by pried up with a small pry bar.

Comment: Thanks James.  The strip is (was) Oak.  I ended up prying and cutting with a knife and finally got it off, in pieces.